# How to get url of current theme in prestashop's .tpl file&

Tags: prestashop

I need to get path of image which is located in www.mysite.com/themes/mytheme/img/image.png

=================================================

I've found the answer here: http://prestalab.ru/wiki/peremennye-v-shablonax.

The path to image in my theme will be: {**$tpl_dir**}img/myimage.png

Comment: In PS1.6 you can simply use `{$tpl_uri}`- **DON'T USE {$tpl_dir}`!** - that one is absolute path on server - you don't want to expose that... :)

Answer (score 26):

**`$tpl_uri`** will return the current theme's path relative to the web root.

Here are some other global variables PrestaShop makes available which may be helpful:

```
$img_ps_dir       // the PrestaShop image directory
$img_cat_dir      // current category's images directory
$img_lang_dir     // current language's images directory
$img_prod_dir     // current product's images directory
$img_manu_dir     // current manufacturer's images directory
$img_sup_dir      // current supplier's images directory
$img_ship_dir     // current carrier's (shipping) images directory
$img_dir          // current theme’s images directory
$css_dir          // current theme’s CSS directory
$js_dir           // current theme’s JavaScript directory
$tpl_dir          // current theme’s directory (physical path on machine)
$tpl_uri          // current theme's directory (web-root relative path)
$modules_dir      // modules directory
$mail_dir         // mail templates directory
$pic_dir          // pictures upload directory
```

Comment: {$tpl_dir} returns the phisical path = c:\wamp\www

Comment: here is a list of available smarty variables in prestashop
http://blog.gofenice.com/prestashop/global-smarty-variables-used-in-prestashop/

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Unfortunately not compatible with PS 1.7 ...

Comment: @GofeniceTechnologies Please provide us a new link.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes its enought to look at code, to see all basic variables assigned:

```
// FrontController Class
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        // Usefull for layout.tpl
        'mobile_device' => $this->context->getMobileDevice(),
        'link' => $link,
        'cart' => $cart,
        'currency' => $currency,
        'cookie' => $this->context->cookie,
        'page_name' => $page_name,
        'hide_left_column' => !$this->display_column_left,
        'hide_right_column' => !$this->display_column_right,
        'base_dir' => _PS_BASE_URL_.__PS_BASE_URI__,
        'base_dir_ssl' => $protocol_link.Tools::getShopDomainSsl().__PS_BASE_URI__,
        'force_ssl' => Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE'),
        'content_dir' => $protocol_content.Tools::getHttpHost().__PS_BASE_URI__,
        'base_uri' => $protocol_content.Tools::getHttpHost().__PS_BASE_URI__.(!Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS') ? 'index.php' : ''),
        'tpl_dir' => _PS_THEME_DIR_,
        'tpl_uri' => _THEME_DIR_,
        'modules_dir' => _MODULE_DIR_,
        'mail_dir' => _MAIL_DIR_,
        'lang_iso' => $this->context->language->iso_code,
        'lang_id' => (int)$this->context->language->id,
        'language_code' => $this->context->language->language_code ? $this->context->language->language_code : $this->context->language->iso_code,
        'come_from' => Tools::getHttpHost(true, true).Tools::htmlentitiesUTF8(str_replace(array('\'', '\\'), '', urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))),
        'cart_qties' => (int)$cart->nbProducts(),
        'currencies' => Currency::getCurrencies(),
        'languages' => $languages,
        'meta_language' => implode(',', $meta_language),
        'priceDisplay' => Product::getTaxCalculationMethod((int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer),
        'is_logged' => (bool)$this->context->customer->isLogged(),
        'is_guest' => (bool)$this->context->customer->isGuest(),
        'add_prod_display' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
        'shop_name' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
        'roundMode' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRICE_ROUND_MODE'),
        'use_taxes' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_TAX'),
        'show_taxes' => (int)(Configuration::get('PS_TAX_DISPLAY') == 1 && (int)Configuration::get('PS_TAX')),
        'display_tax_label' => (bool)$display_tax_label,
        'vat_management' => (int)Configuration::get('VATNUMBER_MANAGEMENT'),
        'opc' => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE'),
        'PS_CATALOG_MODE' => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_CATALOG_MODE') || (Group::isFeatureActive() && !(bool)Group::getCurrent()->show_prices),
        'b2b_enable' => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE'),
        'request' => $link->getPaginationLink(false, false, false, true),
        'PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT' => Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT'),
        'quick_view' => (bool)Configuration::get('PS_QUICK_VIEW'),
        'shop_phone' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_PHONE'),
        'compared_products' => is_array($compared_products) ? $compared_products : array(),
        'comparator_max_item' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_COMPARATOR_MAX_ITEM'),
        'currencyRate' => (float)$currency->getConversationRate(),
        'currencySign' => $currency->sign,
        'currencyFormat' => $currency->format,
        'currencyBlank' => $currency->blank,
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a global smarty variable for mytheme img folder which is - img_dir

See all Smarty Global variables in Prestashop:
http://saidul.songzog.com/my-blog/details/848/smarty-global-variables-in-prestashop.html

Answer (score 2):

On PS 1.6 I found that I needed to add a smarty variable to get my theme's uri. In 
classes/controller/FrontController.php
on about line 333 where tpl_dir is set, I added this line below:

```
'tpl_uri' => _THEME_DIR_,
```

which returns the path the theme.

Answer (score 1):

For PS1.7, you can use

```php
{$urls.img_url}
```

to get a path of the image directory of your current theme.